# Android Studio SVN dialog window issue

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04, android-studio-2.3

Android studio svn conflicts list dialog disappeared or gone behind main studio window and studio is not clickable in ubuntu. How to bring that svn window back to front without restarting android studio or system.

Comment: Please minimize android studio, you will find the dialog. :)

Comment: minimizing android studio is not working.

Comment: You are not able to minimize android studio? or dialog you are not able to see?

Comment: Android studio main window is out of focus and not able to see svn dialog window anywhere.